# SCSS Nesting Issue

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to style an H3 and a p tag inside a div.

I have this block of code (that is not styling the p tag) -

```
.marketing-single-page-titles{
h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  color: $marketing-blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}}}
```

And this block (that IS styling the p tag) -

```
.marketing-single-page-titles p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  color: $marketing-blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Is there a reason the styles are being ignored for the p tag in the first block?

Comment: Update: I put the styles for the p tag above the h3 styles and now it works... What causes this?

Comment: It is because that `p` is not nested inside any `h3`

Comment: Why would you place a `p` within a heading element? A piece of text is either one or the other, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formatting your code correctly will show that the `p` should be nested in the `h3`

The below displays your code formatted correctly, highlighting your issue:

```
.marketing-single-page-titles {
  h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    p {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      position: relative;
      top: -5px;
      color: $marketing-blue;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  }
}
```

How it should be (pay attention to position of closing curly braces):

```
.marketing-single-page-titles {
  h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
    color: $marketing-blue;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I overlooked the parenthesis. I appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. Please remember to accept the answer if it fixed your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The first block will only works if the p is inside the h3 tag; something like:

```
<h3>My nice title with a <p> paragrahp inside</p></h3>
```

Your initial rule for the paragraph concerns translates to

.marketing-single-page-titles h3 p { .....

That's why.